# Get string from Keyword in SuperPower

Tags: c#, superpower

I'm working on a simple scripting language for a work project and I need to create a definition statement of the form `type name = value`. I've been following the [SuperpowerSimpleSql example](https://github.com/nblumhardt/superpower-simple-sql) and have created the tokenizer, which is correctly tokenizing the input.

The problem is coming from creating the TokenListParser for the assignment statement. Currently the parser is defined as this:

```
public static TokenListParser<AumToken, ShmemWord> ShmemWord =
    from keyword in Token.EqualToValueIgnoreCase(AumToken.Keyword, "ShmemWord")
    from name in Token.EqualTo(AumToken.Keyword)
    from equal in Token.EqualTo(AumToken.Assignment)
    from value in Token>EqualTo(AumToken.Number).Apply(Numerics.HexDigitsUInt64)
    select new ShmemWord(name, value);
```

and `ShmemWord` is a simple class with the constructor signature `ShmemWord(string name, ulong value)`.

Am I defining this correctly so far, and how can I convert name to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Token<TKind>` provides `ToStringValue()` for this:

```
     select new ShmemWord(name.ToStringValue(), value);
```